# ListView con Footer Fijo Android

Tags: android, listview

Tengo el siguiente xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/btn_actividadRelative"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listTransacciones"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_actividadRelative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/blanco">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_actividad"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/list_icon"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_extrabold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="@string/strBtnActividad"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#9c88ff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

El cual genera así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que si tengo 1 elemento solo el "Ver todos mis movimientos" aun persiste abajo del todo quedando el espacio en gris. lo que quiero generar es que el botón de "Footer" este siempre abajo del ultimo elemento pero una vez que se complete todo el listado pueda verse siempre.

Intente con `addFooterView` pero el mismo queda oculto hasta scroolear a la ultima celda y no pude dejarlo fijo quisiera.

Cual seria la mejor forma de generar la vista deseada

Pd: Abajo del botón "Ver toda mi actividad" hay mas elementos esto estaría en la mitad de la pantalla

Answer (score 3):

En lo personal me gusta mas el comportamiento que lograste actualmente porque el cliente nunca tendrá que buscar el botón ya que siempre estará en el mismo lugar hayan o no elementos (al final del layout).

Es una de las razones por la que Facebook y muchos otros nunca permitieron el editado "personalizado" de los perfiles de los usuarios, no querían que en cada perfil todos estuvieran buscando donde estaba la info, o las fotos, o cada cosa, sino que fuera fácil de encontrar en el mismo lugar siempre.

Pero bueno, habiendo dicho eso, algo simple que puedes hacer es pasar el botón a la parte superior y listo, así logras lo que necesitas (que no se oculte cuando hayan muchos datos en la lista ni que este hasta el final del layout si esta vacío).

Ahora si quieres seguir con la idea de mantenerlo abajo prueba de esta manera y me dejas saber si te resulta (en lugar de un boton, pon 2, uno anclado al final y el otro siguiendo la cantidad de Items y en tu código cuando Items > n entonces ocultas el botón 1 y muestras el botón 2 y ya.

Aquí te dejo el Xml:

**El `LinearLayout` con los TextView es donde tienes tu SwipeToRefresh y la lista. Yo lo quite porque no tengo ese Nuget de `AndroidX` instalado pero la idea es la misma solo reemplázalo. Ojo de agregar los campos `Orientation`, son necesarios.**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">    

    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"    
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff850">    

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Lista Elemento #1"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#9c88ff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Lista Elemento #2"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#9c88ff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Lista Elemento #3"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#9c88ff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Lista Elemento #etc"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#9c88ff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Lista Elemento #1"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#9c88ff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Lista Elemento #2"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#9c88ff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Lista Elemento #3"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#9c88ff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Lista Elemento #etc"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#9c88ff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        
       
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Lista Elemento #etc"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#9c88ff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        



    </LinearLayout>

    
    <FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"    
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#009450">    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_actividad1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Boton Uno Aqui"
            android:background="#000850"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#9c88ff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_actividad2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Boton Dos Aqui"
            android:background="#000850"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#9c88ff"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

   </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Te quedara asi:

[image: Uno]

[image: dos]

[image: tres]

Comment: Es interesante pero dependiendo el telefono seria la cantidad de N de las filas para esconder o mostrar no seria muy responsive

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, en lo personal a como mencione en el post, a mi solo se me viene una forma de hacerlo "perfecto" sin meternos a calcular tamaños de pantalla y es cambiando de lugar el Btn hacia arriba o dejarlo anclado permanentemente abajo, pero si queremos continuar con esta idea podemos meterle un poco de ".Height" y una division entre el tamaño del CardView para darnos una idea de la cantidad "n" que podríamos usar. Creo que solo es cuestión de probar un par de cosas e ir viendo como se ve mejor.

Comment: Claro es que no costa de mi poder modificar el lugar del boton, pero estar realizandolo con 2 botones ocultar y demas me parece bastante "feo" de realizar pero agradesco tu tiempo por responder e intentar ayudar, pero esta solucion la veo inviable a nivel de proyecto corporativo,

Comment: Feo? Para nada. Tal vez no me explique bien, recuerda que 1 siempre estará oculto. Al final el único que se daría cuenta de eso es el programador ya que el cliente siempre vería uno visible (no hay manera de que el cliente se de cuenta si lo haces bien). De hecho considero es una muy buena y simple solución al tema, ya que considero para esto no hay razón de hacer un algoritmo super complejo para que maneje este "inconveniente" mas que el Visibility. Pero bueno, tal vez nos compartes que solución ocupas al final. Mucha suerte con la UI